# Extracting data from xml

Tags: c#, xml

Im trying to extract data from the xml file

```
<root response="True">
<movie title="True Grit" year="1969" rated="N/A" released="11 Jun 1969" runtime="128 min" genre="Adventure, Western, Drama" director="Henry Hathaway" writer="Charles Portis (novel), Marguerite Roberts (screenplay)" actors="John Wayne, Glen Campbell, Kim Darby, Jeremy Slate" plot="A drunken, hard-nosed U.S. Marshal and a Texas Ranger help a stubborn young woman track down her father's murderer in Indian territory." language="English" country="USA" awards="Won 1 Oscar. Another 7 wins & 5 nominations." poster="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNTE3NDYzOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTU5MzY0MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg" metascore="N/A" imdbRating="7.4" imdbVotes="26,487" imdbID="tt0065126" type="movie" tomatoMeter="90" tomatoImage="certified" tomatoRating="7.9" tomatoReviews="48" tomatoFresh="43" tomatoRotten="5" tomatoConsensus="N/A" tomatoUserMeter="83" tomatoUserRating="3.8" tomatoUserReviews="24,949" DVD="21 Mar 2000" BoxOffice="N/A" Production="Paramount Home Video" Website="N/A"/>
</root>
```

i have written the code

```
var res= doc.Element("year");
MessageBox.Show(""+res);
```

the xml file is loaded but im getting empty value on the messagebox
how can i get the value from each node

Comment: Answer to your second question is `var poster = (string)doc.Root.Element("movie").Attribute("poster");` you see to string representation of XAttribute. You should retrieve attribute value instead. Note - adding questions to original question is not good. If you have another question, then just create new separate question

Comment: thanks a lot figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`year` is not an element, it's an `attribute`,try this:

```
doc.Descendants("movie").First().Attribute("year").Value;
```

Comment: Note - for this sample xml you don't need to create enumerator over all movie elements, because there is only one. Also retrieving value directly may throw exception if attribute is not there (casting to nullable type is better in this case)

Answer (score 2):

`year` is *attribute* of `movie` *element*:

```
var year = (int)doc.Root.Element("movie").Attribute("year");
```